# intermittent strange tomcat issues deploying war file

Tags: java, tomcat

I have attempted to search this issue first, but found nothing with this exact issue.

I have an intermittent issue when I attempt to deploy a war file on our tomcat server. It occasionally fails with the following, forcing us to `bounce tomcat` before we can deploy.

`Jan 08, 2013 11:50:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
 SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps  /somewar.war
 javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:132)`

Once we bounce tomcat, we can deploy the war file without issues. In fact, this failure is so random that I can't even reproduce this correctly.

Has anyone have any ideas on what could be going on?.

java version:

Java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

tomcat version:

Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
Server built:   Jul 3 2012 11:31:52
Server number:  7.0.29.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.18-308.16.1.el5
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_09-b05
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Comment: what's the method of deploying the war file? simple copying to webapps directory? from remote system? if so - could be possible that tomcat starts deploying partially copied file and fails.

Comment: The war files are uploaded via the Tomcat Web Application Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to consistently reproduce this issue by deploying two .war files at the same time with tomcat shutdown and then restarting tomcat. (I doubt it's relevant but the servlets for each .war file were very similar and had a xerces dependency also)

The issue appears to have been fixed by changing the web.xml file for each of the .war files as follows:

Change the 'load-on-startup' element value to be -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is conflicting JAR files, i.e. you have multiple identical classes on your classpath. You can determine where a class is coming from inside your code with the following:

```
System.out.println(javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.class.getResource("SAXParserFactory.class"));
```